# Проблема с обращением к файлу через GET

Tags: php, html

Всем привет.
Средствами PHP пытаюсь обратиться к файлу, лежащему в папке. Через GET-параметр передаю необходимое наименование файла.

```
//это index.php
$dir = "./abitListsDirections";
$a = scandir($dir);
foreach($a as $key => $value){ 
    echo '<a href="./show_napr.php?napr_name='.$value.'" title="Просмотр списка" data-pjax="0">Открыть</a>';
}
```

С относительно короткими названиями все работает, но если название слишком длинное то часть наименования обрезается и полностью не передается в параметре "napr_name".
Пример подходящего названия:

```
Архитектура_07.03.01_Бакалавр_Ц_Очная_ЦП_Архитектура.HTML
```

Пример длинного названия:

```
Пушкин_Факультет  иностранных языков_44.03.01_Педагогическое образование_Иностранный язык (английския язык)_Бакалавриат_Б_Федеральный бюджет_Очная_Б_Педагогическое образование_Иностранный язык (английския язык).HTML
```

Последний обрезается вот так:
[image: Изображение]

Генерируемый код следующий:
Первая и третья ссылки - рабочие(в первой я обрезал название самого файла), а вторая ссылка не работает.

```html
<a href="./show_napr.php?napr_name=Пушкин_Факультет  иностранных языков_44.03.01_Педагогическое образование_Иностранный язык (английския язык).HTML" title="Просмотр списка" data-pjax="0">Открыть</a>
<a href="./show_napr.php?napr_name=Пушкин_Факультет  иностранных языков_44.03.01_Педагогическое образование_Иностранный язык (английския язык)_Бакалавриат_Б_Федеральный бюджет_" title="Просмотр списка" data-pjax="0">Открыть</a>
<a href="./show_napr.php?napr_name=Пушкин_Факультет юридический_40.03.01_Юр_Гр_Бакалавриат_Б_Рег_Очная_Б_Юриспруденция_Гражданское право.HTML" title="Просмотр списка" data-pjax="0">Открыть</a>
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, с чем это может быть связано и как это можно починить?

Comment: Добавьте примеры слишком длинных названий.  Вероятно дело не в длине, а в определённых символах.

Comment: Задавая вопросы, связанные с генерацией хтмл кода через РНР, необходимо всегда приводить не только тот код, который занимается генерацией, но и **конечный результат**. Чтобы не на пальцах объяснять "вот некоторые орбрезаются", а показывать реальный конкретный результат работы своего кода.

Comment: ограничения длины GET запроса может быт с этим связано (2-8Кбайт). если и правда параметры длинный. С другой, стороны, если у вас в названии есть неэкранированный `&` то он тоже сломает все

Comment: и нет, конечный результат - это не скриншот из браузера. РНР не создает не картинку на экране. Картинку рисует браузер. А РНР создает HTML код. Который можно посмотреть в браузере нажав кнопку Ctrl-U

Comment: Добавил примеры

Comment: **и нет, конечный результат - это не скриншот из браузера**

Answer (score 0):

Я разобрался, все дело в ограничении винды на максимальную длину имени файла. Тоесть из какой-то программы я могу создать файл с названием, нужным мне, но при чтении возвращается количество символов, равное ограничению(вместе с символами каталогов). У меня это 260 символов.